# Migrate database on each deployment to gcloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have an gcloud app configured to use the Cloud SQL instance in app.yaml:

```
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: <instance-name>
```

After I deploy the app, `/cloudsql/<instance-name>` is available and it is possible to connect to the database through the socket file.

In order to migrate the database schema with each deployment I need a deployment command in `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN yarn run sequelize db:migrate
```

However the `/cloudsql` is not available when `Dockerfile` is executed.

`RUN ls /cloudsql` leads to `ls: /cloudsql: No such file or directory`.

What is a way to make `/cloudsql` available in this context?
Is there other best practice to migrate the database in gcloud deployment?

Comment: Make use of entrypoint in dockerfile that will execute some init script that has db migration commands.

Comment: something similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56875494/6790948

Comment: It is not a good idea to do this in Dockerfile startup scripts. Each time your app "cold-starts" the startup scripts run. Initializing databases should be performed independently of your containers and in a controlled consisted method.

Answer (score 0):

Performing database migrations with Django on Google App Engine and Cloud SQL. It has a free tier that is sufficient for most small businesses and hobby websites, and is very easy to deploy and maintain. Some of those websites are written in Django, a recommended Python web framework.

manage.py migrate command against your App Engine Standard instance, with a Cloud SQL database

There is a solution/workaround: you can connect to Cloud SQL from your local machine and execute the manage.py migrate on your local machine but have the changes be made to your cloud instance.

To do this, you need to add your Cloud SQL database to your settings file. Your production instance is probably using sockets, but from your local machine you need to use the IP adress:

https://medium.com/@mrdatainsight/performing-database-migrations-with-django-on-google-app-engine-and-cloud-sql-c7fd298581b4