# Running Django migrations in Dockerfile.template appears to skip and goes straight to running the server

Tags: docker

This is my Dockerfile.template

```
...
CMD python3 manage.py makemigrations --noinput
CMD python3 manage.py migrate --noinput
CMD python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
...
```

But for some reasons the application goes straight into serving

I'm running the docker container like so:

```
docker run -t --rm -p 8000:8000 {myimage}
```

I found this behavior to be strange so I decided to hop in

```
docker exec -it d2836730ae55 bash
python3 manage.py makemigrations --noinput
python3 manage.py migrate --noinput
```

And this runs fine, so it seems like `docker run` somehow is skipping the other commands. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A container only has one command, and every `CMD` except the last one is ignored.  [How do you perform Django database migrations when using Docker-Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992867/how-do-you-perform-django-database-migrations-when-using-docker-compose) discusses two primary ways to run migrations (in a separate container, or making `CMD` be a shell script).

Comment: Aaaah that makes sense.