# while using docker migrate cmd "django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution"

Tags: python, docker, django-models

getting this error while migrate cmd (docker-compose exec web python manage.py migrate) previously
tried all solutions available on stack-overflow. following Django for professionals book .

#docker-compose.yml#

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports: 
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

#dockerfile#

```
FROM python:3.9.6

#set environment variables

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

#set work directory
WORKDIR /code

#install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

# Copy project
COPY . /code/
```

#setting.py#

````
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432
    }

}```
````

Comment: Nothing you show here tries to run migrations.  What's the actual command you're running, and where are you running it from?  Also see [How do you perform Django database migrations when using Docker-Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992867/how-do-you-perform-django-database-migrations-when-using-docker-compose)

Comment: running ```docker-compose exec python manage.py makemigration```

Comment: running ```docker-compose exec python manage.py makemigration```  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py:121: RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': could not translate host name 
"db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

  warnings.warn(
Migrations for 'users':
  users/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model CustomUser   from that i'm getting this

Comment: ```docker-compose exec python manage.py migrate``` i'm getting the the above error.