# Is there an elegant hook into mysql/postgres docker-entrypoint.sh to run migrations on every container start?

Tags: postgresql, docker

Say I have a series of SQL statements in a file `idempotent_init.sql`, that I would like to run with every startup of a postgres container (not just the first startup).

The default postgres/mysql images come with an [entrypoint script](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh#L327) which does something close - it auto-executes scripts in a certain folder, but only if the db volume has never been initialized before.

I could copy and modify this existing entrypoint script to do what I need, something like:

```
if [ -z "$DATABASE_ALREADY_EXISTS" ]; then
    ....
fi

docker_temp_server_start "$@"
# .sql files added to /docker-entrypoint-alwaysrun.d/ will always be executed
docker_process_init_files /docker-entrypoint-alwaysrun.d/*
docker_temp_server_stop
```

however this would copy of the entrypoint script would lose track of upstream changes if a future image updates it.

Is there a way to insert a command that runs after the entrypoint, but before the final `CMD ["postgres"]` [in the db image](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/Dockerfile-alpine.template#L217C1-L217C17)?

Or is the recommended approach for idempotent init scripts to be run from a separate container that `depends_on` the db container?

Comment: Since the application code and the database need to match, the common approach is to let the code run any migrations needed. If you have your migrations in the database image, there's a risk that your code and database will get out of sync.

Comment: [How do you perform Django database migrations when using Docker-Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992867/how-do-you-perform-django-database-migrations-when-using-docker-compose) might have some suggestions.  As @HansKilian notes, these are focused on running migrations from the application container, and they don't usually require restarting the database.

Comment: Yeah, I think you guys are on the right track after all - I played around to get a working solution and it was a good learning experience for docker, but pragmatically it's adding startup time for the container. It's really a "dev mode" convenience. My only hesitation is around needing to maintain the postgres root credentials on all application containers.

Answer (score 0):

Got to a working solution, which involves specifying a new entrypoint wrapper. This specific one is for postgres, although the official mysql and other db images have a similar entrypoint structure:

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM postgres:15.3-alpine

ENV POSTGRES_USER=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

# /docker-entrypoint-startdb.d is my designated folder 
# where scripts are always run upon container start
RUN mkdir /docker-entrypoint-startdb.d
ADD on_startup.sql /docker-entrypoint-startdb.d/.

# wrapper around postgres image's default docker-entrypoint.sh
COPY startup_sql.sh /.
ENTRYPOINT ["/startup_sql.sh"]
```

and the accompanying `startup_sql.sh`, which is the new entrypoint:

`startup_sql.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

.   /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh --source-only

if [ "$(id -u)" = '0' ]; then
    # restart script as postgres user instead of root
    exec su-exec postgres "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@"
fi

# run original main to handle all initialization
# we have not yet set the postgres command, so the 
# db will not actually start yet
_main "$@"

# temporarily start the server, run startdb scripts, exit
docker_setup_env
docker_temp_server_start "$@"
docker_process_init_files /docker-entrypoint-startdb.d/*
docker_temp_server_stop

# finally, exec postgres to start the server
set -- postgres "$@"
exec "$@"
```

In hindsight, this is a 3-liner (server start, `docker_process_init_files`, server stop) - it might be less effort to just maintain a copy of the upstream `docker-entrypoint.sh` and just make a note to update if ever updating the base image.

In practice I'm also less convinced about the overhead of the idempotent startup sql on every container start - it's a dev mode convenience but wouldn't make the cut for a prod service.