# I cannot perform migrations in django + docker + postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have two Docker containers on a virtual machine with Debian OS - one with Django and the other with PostgreSQL. Here is the code of the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  server:
      build: .
      command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
      volumes:
        - .:/usr/src/app/
      networks:
        - my_network
      ports:
        - 8000:8000
      depends_on:
        - pgdb
  pgdb:
      image: postgres
      networks:
        - my_network
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      container_name: pgdb
      volumes:
        - pgdbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      ports:
        - 5432:5432
volumes:
  pgdbdata: null
networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Here is an excerpt from the settings.py file responsible for connecting to the database:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'pgdb',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

When I run docker-compose up, both services start without errors. I can connect to my database from outside using pgadmin and access my website. However, when I attempt to run migrations in Django, it raises an error:
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "pgdb" to address: Name or service not known.

Originally, I didn't specify in Docker Compose that these containers belong to the same network. Attempting to add the same network to both of them didn't make any difference.

Comment: [How do you perform Django database migrations when using Docker-Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992867/how-do-you-perform-django-database-migrations-when-using-docker-compose) discusses a couple of paths to run this, either automatically or by `docker-compose run server ./manage.py migrate`.  Does that question have the details you need?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to connect to PostgreSQL outside of the Docker container. In this case, you should use "localhost" as the hostname. For the migrations part, you should include it either in your Dockerfile or Docker Compose to run automatically when your Docker is building.

Here is some example:

in Dockerfile:

```
CMD python manage.py makemigrations && \
    python manage.py migrate && \
    python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

in docker-compose.yml file:

```
     command: >
       sh -c "
       pipenv run python manage.py makemigrations &&
       pipenv run python manage.py migrate &&
       pipenv run python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
       "
```