# OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am using django on a project and we are switching from sqlite3 to postgres so we need to add postgres to docker. For some reason the webservice wont connect to postgres. Here is my docker-compose and settings.

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=pipeline_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=pipeline_service
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks: 
      - django
  webservice:
    build:
      context: ./webservice
      dockerfile: WebService.Dockerfile
    command: python ./src/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks: 
      - django
    links:
      - db:db
  djangoq:
    build:
      context: ./webservice
      dockerfile: WebService.Dockerfile
    command: python ./src/manage.py qcluster
    ports:
      - "8001:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks: 
      - django
    links:
      - db:db
  ui:
    build:
      context: ./ui
      dockerfile: UI.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4200:80"
    depends_on:
      - webservice
networks:
  django:
    driver: bridge
```

```
DATABASES = {
    # 'default': {
    #     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    #     'NAME': 'pipeline_service.sqlite3',
    # }
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'pipeline_service',
        'USER': 'pipeline_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST':'db',
        'PORT':'5432'
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

I have found several other people with this issue and most of the solutions were adding networks to the docker-compose.yml file or setting the container_name for postgres, but those haven't worked for me.

Comment: What is the exact error?  What part of the process is producing the error?  (For example, does `docker-compose build` run successfully?)  In the name of simplifying things I might suggest _deleting_ the `container_name:` and `networks:` settings, along with obsolete options like `links:`; they aren't needed for normal inter-container communication.

Comment: Simple: there is no DNS entry for "db". Try using the IP address to connect.

Comment: @DavidMaze the error is "OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known". I first tried it without those and it makes no difference. I added them based on answers I have seen on other people's question about this.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe what would be the IP for the postgres docker? Localhost or 127.0.0.1 does not work either. I have seen several people say to use the name of the service rather than the ip for this.

Comment: @DavidMaze build fails because the webservice tries to run "manage.py migrate" but cant access the database

Comment: See [How do you perform Django database migrations when using Docker-Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992867/how-do-you-perform-django-database-migrations-when-using-docker-compose).  You can never run migrations or otherwise access a database from an image build.

Comment: I just tried running it without the migrate, attaching to the webservice and running migrate and I still got the same error. Also, it worked with sqlite from the image build

Comment: actually, looks like that was a port issue. I'm getting different errors now with my migrations, but I'll look into that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per David's comment, you cannot run migrate with the dockerfile, but it does work as a service. I ended up making a second docker-compose file for postgres which started postgres and ran the migrations. This is also helpful because the database gets deleted whenever docker is down, so you dont have to restart postgres with everything else.

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=pipeline_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<password>
      - POSTGRES_DB=pipeline_service
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  db_setup:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build:
      context: ./webservice
      dockerfile: WebService.Dockerfile
    command: python ./src/manage.py migrate
```