# Schema not being created in docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to build a web project with various docker containers. When I create the container of my db I run an initial script creating users and database to work with, but happens that schema and tables are never created. This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.db
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9000:8080
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    
  api:
    build: ./app
    command: uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80 --ssl-keyfile=./localhost.key --ssl-certfile=./localhost.crt --reload
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    depends_on:
      - db
    # environment:
    #   DATABASE_URL: postgresql://youruser:yourpassword@db/yourdbname

  web:
    build: ./web
    ports:
      - 7000:8080
    volumes:
      - ./web:/web

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

This my Dockerfile.db:

```
FROM postgres:16.1-bullseye

COPY db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

and this db.sql:

```
-- Database generated with pgModeler (PostgreSQL Database Modeler).
-- pgModeler version: 0.9.4
-- PostgreSQL version: 13.0
-- Project Site: pgmodeler.io
-- Model Author: ---

-- Database creation must be performed outside a multi lined SQL file. 
-- These commands were put in this file only as a convenience.
-- 
-- object: new_database | type: DATABASE --
-- DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS new_database;


-- ddl-end --
CREATE USER sa WITH PASSWORD 'admin';

CREATE DATABASE caillou;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE caillou TO sa;
-- ddl-end --


-- object: app | type: SCHEMA --
-- DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS app CASCADE;
-- Create the schema if it doesn't exist
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS app;
SET search_path TO pg_catalog,public,app;

-- Change ownership of the schema to your_app_user
ALTER SCHEMA app OWNER TO sa;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA app TO sa;
-- ddl-end --
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA app
FOR ROLE sa
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO sa;
-- ddl-end --

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
-- object: app."Users" | type: TABLE --
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS app."Users" CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE app."Users" (
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    username text NOT NULL,
    password text NOT NULL,
    email text NOT NULL,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    surname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    age smallint NOT NULL,
    iban text,
    CONSTRAINT "Users_pk" PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
-- ddl-end --
ALTER TABLE app."Users" OWNER TO sa;
-- ddl-end --

-- object: app."Packages" | type: TABLE --
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS app."Packages" CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE app."Packages" (
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    "id_Users" uuid,
    CONSTRAINT package_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
-- ddl-end --
ALTER TABLE app."Packages" OWNER TO sa;
-- ddl-end --

-- object: "Users_fk" | type: CONSTRAINT --
-- ALTER TABLE app."Packages" DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS "Users_fk" CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE app."Packages" ADD CONSTRAINT "Users_fk" FOREIGN KEY ("id_Users")
REFERENCES app."Users" (id) MATCH FULL
ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
-- ddl-end --

-- object: app."Files" | type: TABLE --
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS app."Files" CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE app."Files" (
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    "id_Packages" uuid,
    content_type varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    filename varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    file_size bigint NOT NULL,
    content bytea NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "Files_pk" PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
-- ddl-end --
ALTER TABLE app."Files" OWNER TO sa;
-- ddl-end --

-- object: "Packages_fk" | type: CONSTRAINT --
-- ALTER TABLE app."Files" DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS "Packages_fk" CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE app."Files" ADD CONSTRAINT "Packages_fk" FOREIGN KEY ("id_Packages")
REFERENCES app."Packages" (id) MATCH FULL
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
-- ddl-end --

-- object: app."Links" | type: TABLE --
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS app."Links" CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE app."Links" (
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    "id_Packages" uuid,
    times smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    price money NOT NULL,
    type text NOT NULL,
    timeout timestamp,
    is_valid bool NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "Links_pk" PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
-- ddl-end --
ALTER TABLE app."Links" OWNER TO sa;
-- ddl-end --

-- object: "Packages_fk" | type: CONSTRAINT --
-- ALTER TABLE app."Links" DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS "Packages_fk" CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE app."Links" ADD CONSTRAINT "Packages_fk" FOREIGN KEY ("id_Packages")
REFERENCES app."Packages" (id) MATCH FULL
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
-- ddl-end --

-- object: app."Purchases" | type: TABLE --
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS app."Purchases" CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE app."Purchases" (
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    "id_Packages" uuid,
    successful bool,
    price money,
    CONSTRAINT "Purchases_pk" PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
-- ddl-end --
ALTER TABLE app."Purchases" OWNER TO sa;
-- ddl-end --

-- object: "Packages_fk" | type: CONSTRAINT --
-- ALTER TABLE app."Purchases" DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS "Packages_fk" CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE app."Purchases" ADD CONSTRAINT "Packages_fk" FOREIGN KEY ("id_Packages")
REFERENCES app."Packages" (id) MATCH FULL
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
-- ddl-end --
```

I don't now if I am doing something wrong or if my approach is incorrect and I should try creating the database in some other way. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'd prefer using your application framework's migration system over writing out `CREATE TABLE` statements in a database initialization script.  This will work with non-Docker setups too, and it will work if you do make some change to the database without deleting the entire database.  [How do you perform Django database migrations when using Docker-Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992867/how-do-you-perform-django-database-migrations-when-using-docker-compose) might be a good starting point.

Comment: The thing is my project is being built with FastAPI, and alembic as a migration tool seems quite complicated rigth now as I am just building an MVP. Either way, what migration system would you recomend?