# Building docker python project that uses dbmate

Tags: python, docker, schema-migration

From what I've read, migrations can be run separately from the application (dbmate), or as part of the bootstrap of the application (Flyway in the JVM).

I prefer the latter approach, yet most tools in python (and in general) use the former approach.

My intention is to build a docker image that once run, evolves the db/runs the migrations before building the db engine. But how?

When I build the docker image, I first build a skimmed venv that includes the sourcecode of my app and the runtime dependencies. Migration CLI tools like dbmate and alembic are not included. Besides, they don't read from the packages using `pkg_resources`  nor `importlib.resources`, they're intended to be used on the workspace, not by the bundled running app.

I don't know if I'm overcomplicating stuff, so I'd like to know how to achieve migrations during the bootstrap of my application, and not as part of an independent pipeline or the deployment pipeline.

I prefer it that way given that when I'm running tests, I like running pg docker images and run migrations on them (using testcontainers). If I use the migrations as a "separate process", those tests are very complicated to get running.

If you think that such approach is very complicated, please state why, and share how it is usually done so that evolutions and deployment happen one after the other.

Comment: Question...do you store your docker image in a repo? We do this in prod and map pulled code to the `up`ped images, removes quite a bit of bloat and ensures your env can be pulled securely (i.e. without code or rebuilds). I use Django and run migrations when needed but the DB state remains in latest state during CI/CD regardless of implementation as migrations are run (if setup) in `pytest` automatically

Comment: Any tools you need to run need to be included in your image.  (Your application needs to be included in the image as well; if you're using an interpreted language like Python, that means its source code too.)  [How do you perform Django database migrations when using Docker-Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992867/how-do-you-perform-django-database-migrations-when-using-docker-compose) discusses a couple of approaches with a slightly different Python-based tool set, will a setup like those work for you?

Comment: Ginna check... I'll ve deploying it in a k8s cluster, so using the startup containers could work, although it just makes it way too complex

Comment: Startup containers are a good k8s solution, but if you want to keep it simpler, then define an entrypoint shell script (or any executable) that can invoke the migrations, then `exec` the actual applications.