# 'ProgrammingError: column does not exist' in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, docker-compose

I've been moving development of my website over to using Docker. I replaced sqlite as my database with postgresql then ran the command `docker-compose exec web python manage.py migrate` in my Docker environment. I also updated `MEDIA ROOT` and `MEDIA` settings in my settings.py file and updated mysite/urls.py. When I go to `127.0.0.1:8000/admin` to the look at stored/uploaded files I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

The above exception (column human_requirementschat.alias does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "human_requirementschat"."id", "human_requirementscha...
                                              ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 688, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 62, in _wrapper_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 242, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 2065, in changelist_view
    "selection_note": _("0 of %(cnt)s selected") % {"cnt": len(cl.result_list)},
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 380, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1881, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 91, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
              
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1560, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 102, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
           
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/human/requirementschat/
Exception Value: column human_requirementschat.alias does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "human_requirementschat"."id", "human_requirementscha...
                                              ^
```

Here are the relevant files:

urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings # new
from django.conf.urls.static import static # new
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
#from translator import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('homepage.urls')),#redirects to transcribe/,
    path('transcribe/', include('transcribe.urls')),
    path('human/', include('human.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]+ static(
settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
) # new
```

settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
"default": env.dj_db_url("DATABASE_URL",
default="postgres://postgres@db/postgres")
}#new

MEDIA_URL='/media/' #new
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR/'media' #new
```

models.py:

```
class RequirementsChat(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=38)
    #id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, max_length=37)
    #id_temp = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    due_date = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    subtitle_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    transcript_file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    additional_requirements = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    task_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
class UploadedFile(models.Model):
    input_file = models.FileField(upload_to='human_upload/')#new
    chat_id = models.CharField(max_length=33, null= True)
    requirements_chat = models.ForeignKey(RequirementsChat, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='human_upload', null=True)
```

I deleted all my migration files and ran `makemigrations`, `makemigrations human` and `migrate` several times but the same error always occurs. Grateful for any help.

Comment: I'm guessing a column name casing issue. What is the column name as shown using `psql`? You are probably going to end up needing to use [db_column](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#db-column) in your field definitions.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver How to see the column name as shown using `psql`?

Comment: `\d human_requirementschat`

Comment: You deleted your migration files, what about the database? Also given you say you run this using Docker, how did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I'm new to this and still not sure what you mean. However I just realized that that after running migrate it responds with:

```Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, human, sessions, transcribe
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.```
So I guess migrations aren't being applied. Not sure what could be the reason.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I'm not sure how to delete the database(postgresql) so I'll look into hpw to do that and try again.
The docker commands I used are `docker-compose exec web python manage.py makemigrations appName` and `docker-compose exec web python manage.py migrate`.  I also just realized that that after running `migrate` it responds with: ```Operations to perform:   Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, human, sessions, transcribe Running migrations:   No migrations to apply```. So I guess migrations aren't being applied. Not sure what could be the reason.

Comment: Containers are ephemeral, why are you running makemigrations in your container? That command generates code that needs to be stored.

Comment: Duplicate of: [How do you perform Django database migrations when using Docker-Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992867/how-do-you-perform-django-database-migrations-when-using-docker-compose/78119208)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tthheemmaannii

First, please try to print this variable DATABASES in your settings.py to see what the actual database is in use.

Then if there is no data in the current database, try to create new database and using that one to create migrations and migrate from there.

Comment: Hi. I printed the variable and ran `logs` and got
```... {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql', 'NAME': 'postgres', 'USER': ' postgres', 'PASSWORD': 'postgres', 'HOST': 'db', 'PORT': 5432}}
db-1   |
db-1   | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization ...```

I'm still in development and my database shouldn't contain any data. So I'm ok with throwing away my current one. But i'm not sure how to 'create new database and using that one to create migrations and migrate from there'.

Comment: How about this:

docker-compose exec db psql -U  postgres -W -c "CREATE DATABASE db1"

Then change the db name in django setting to 'db1' and try to run the migrate command?

Comment: This works, thanks. Should I delete the previous database by running `docker exec -it <container-id> psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "DROP DATABASE postgres;"`? Can I then replace my new db1 database with a new database named postgres?

Comment: @tthheemmaannii, Yes, you can.