# Run the migration script in the container

Tags: database, docker, containers, migration, database-migration

I built a rest api application using [nest.js](https://nestjs.com/), with the migration source code in one project, so that when I created an image and then a container, the migration source code was in both the image and my application container. Do you have any suggestions as to the best way to run my current containerized database migration script? Thank You.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What problems are you running into?  [How do you perform Django database migrations when using Docker-Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992867/how-do-you-perform-django-database-migrations-when-using-docker-compose) is a different technology stack, but the high-level options it describes for running migrations (in an entrypoint wrapper script, via `docker-compose run`) would be applicable anywhere in Docker.