When using the command docker-compose exec web python core/manage.py makemigration accountss I see the error "No module named 'accounts"
When using the command docker-compose exec web python core/manage.py makemigration accountss I see the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'accounts'
INSTALLED_APPS:
enter image description here
The error that is observed:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/core/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/code/core/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 178, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1310, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1324, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'accounts'


when makemigrations, I saw the above error

just write the app_name only.

It was tested but the problem was not solved

In error, module not found there's a something package with name account?

Does this other stackoverflow answer help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992867/how-do-you-perform-django-database-migrations-when-using-docker-compose

Checking in INSTALLED_APPS at settings.py file. then you must delete 'accounts' module. it caused this module you deleted before.
